# Lambda Calculus change of variable and application question

Tags: haskell, lambda, lambda-calculus

I am studying Haskell and I am learning what is an abstraction, substitution (beta equivalence), application, free and bound variables (alpha equivalence), but I have some doubts resolving these exercises, I don't know if my solutions are correct.

Make the following substitutions

```
1. (λ x → y x x) [x:= f z] 
Sol. (\x -> y x x) =>α (\w -> y w w) =>α (\w -> x w w) =>β (\w -> f z w w)

2. ((λ x → y x x) x) [y:= x]
Sol. ((\x -> y x x)x) =>α (\w -> y w w)[y:= x] = (\w -> x w w)     

3. ((λ x → y x) (λ y → y x) y) [x:= f y]
Sol. aproximation, i don't know how to do it:  ((\x -> y x)(\y -> y x) y) =>β 
(\x -> y x)y x)[x:= f y] =>β  y x [x:= f y] = y f y

4. ((λ x → λ y → y x x) y) [y:= f z]
Sol aproximation, ((\x -> (\y -> (y x x))) y) =>β ((\y -> (y x x)) y) =>α ((\y -> (y x x)) f z)
```

Another doubt that I have is if can I run these expressions on [this website](https://lambdacalc.io/)? It is a Lambda Calculus Calculator but I do not know how to run these tests.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Haskell specifically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `1. (λ x → y x x) [x:= f z]`
> Sol. `(\x -> y x x) =>α (\w -> y w w) =>α (\w -> x w w) =>β (\w -> f z w w)`

No, you can't rename `y`, it's free in `(λ x → y x x)`. Only *bound* variables can be (consistently) α-renamed. But only *free* variables can be substituted, and there's no free `x` in that lambda term.

> `2. ((λ x → y x x) x) [y:= x]`
> Sol. `((\x -> y x x)x) =>α (\w -> y w w)[y:= x] = (\w -> x w w)`

Yes, substituting `x` for `y` would allow it to be captured by the `λ x`, so you indeed must α-rename the `x` in `(λ x → y x x)` first to some new unique name as you did, but you've dropped the application to the free `x` for some reason. You can't just omit parts of a term, so it's `((\w -> y w w) x)[y:= x]`. Now perform the substitution. Note you're not asked to perform the β-reduction of the resulting term, just the substitution.

I'll leave the other two out. Just follow the rules carefully. It's easy if you rename all bound names to unique names first, even if the renaming is not strictly required, for instance

```
((λ x → y x) (λ y → y x) y) [x:= f y]   -->
((λ w → y w) (λ z → z x) y) [x:= f y]
```

The "unique" part includes also the free variables used in the substitution terms, that might get captured after being substituted otherwise (i.e. without the renaming being performed first, in the terms in which they are being substituted). That's why we had to rename the bound `y` in the above term, -- because `y` appears free in the substitution term. We didn't have to rename the bound `x` but it made it easier that way.

Comment: Ok thanks bro for your help. Now I am understanding a bit more about these. So, about you have said, maybe the Sol. for part 3 is `((\x -> y x)(\y -> y x) y) =>β ((y(\y ->(y x)))y) =>α 
((y(\w ->(w x)))y)[x:= f y] = ((y(\w ->(w f y)))y) `    and for part 4 is not to  possible to make the substitution because 'y' is a bound variable, right?

Comment: there is only one `x` in `((λ w → y w) (λ z → z x) y) [x:= f y]`, just replace it with `(f y)`. again, you are not asked to perform the beta-reduction afterwards, according to your question. but if you wanted to beta reduce it, then it's just some more substitutions to perform in the same fashion. for #4, not quite. it is bound inside the lambda expression, but it is free where used as its argument. the bound `y` can be renamed, so it is less confusing, and again, there will be only one `y` left -- the free `y`, so it'll be easy to perform the substitution.